# NoSuchMethodError exception when connecting to HBase

Tags: scala, sbt, hbase, apache-storm

I'm getting a peculiar exception when trying accessing HBase from Scala code.

Here is the long version of that story:

I installed HBase 1.2.6 in standalone mode on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04).
Next I tried to execute the following code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.compress.Compression.Algorithm
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, HColumnDescriptor, HTableDescriptor, TableName}

object HelloWorld {
    private val TABLE_NAME = "MY_TABLE_NAME_TOO"
    private val CF_DEFAULT = "DEFAULT_COLUMN_FAMILY"

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val config: Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()

        val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config)
        val admin = connection.getAdmin

        val table = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME))
        table.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(CF_DEFAULT).setCompressionType(Algorithm.NONE))

        System.out.print("Creating table. ")
        admin.createTable(table)
        System.out.println(" Done.")
    }
}
```

The `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "myapp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.storm" % "storm-core" % "1.0.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.2.6" exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.2.6" exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.8.0" exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-protocol" % "1.2.6" exclude("org.slf4j","slf4j-log4j12")
```

I execute the code from sbt using these commands:

```
$ sbt
> compile
> run
```

I get the following error:

```
[info] Running hbase.HelloWorld
[info] 566  [main] WARN  o.a.h.u.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[error] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil.hasKerberosTicket(Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;)Z
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<init>(UserGroupInformation.java:652)
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:843)
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:802)
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:675)
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.<init>(User.java:293)
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.getCurrent(User.java:191)
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.UserProvider.getCurrent(UserProvider.java:167)
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:215)
[error]         at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:119)
[error]         at hbase.HelloWorld$.main(HelloWorld.scala:48)
[error]         at hbase.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.scala)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Jun 12, 2017 2:56:48 PM
```

The exception occurs when the line

```
val connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config)
```

is reached.

It makes no sense to me. I hope someone can shed a light on this one.

Answer (score 0):

All works well after removing this dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.storm" % "storm-core" % "1.0.3"
```

Apparently using Storm and HBase together can be problematic. (I'm not sure how to solve this though.)